# How to link apk file with specific android version and phone hardware setup?

Tags: android, apk

I created an apk set file with extension `apks` for React Native app and would like to test it on android phones. My question is how to link the apk file name with specific android version and phone hardware so the right apk file will be installed. For some of the file name, google has targeted android version listed online without hardware specified.

Here is the list of apk files in distribution:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better build an app [bundle](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle), then the delivery of splits is being handled by Google Play.

Comment: The situation is that initially I have to send the individual apk file for testing purpose.

Comment: An `*.abb` bundle can have all of these configurations, depending how splits or configured. Else one can just upload a single `*.apk`, with `arm64_v8a` and `armeabi_v7a` assembly and no resource splits.